# Modified by present the 'created by'

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer

We're using Sharepoint online. For some reason, when I set a field as value 'modified by' via a WF (in SPD) I get the value 'created by'. In many cases I know for sure that the user who modified the item isn't the one that created it.
Does anyone encountered the same problem and know how to solve it?

Comment: can you add the screenshot for WF steps

Comment: I think the screenshot will not make it clear. I'll describe it here - sent an email to the manager > wait the field 'status' equal to 'Apporved' > set field 'approver name' as 'current item:modified by'. I made few tests and i noticed that the field 'approver name' set as the 'current item:created by' although I know for sure that the last one who modified the item is the manager. Does it help?